# sudo: ruby: command not found after ssh

Tags: ssh, sudo, ruby, amazon-ec2

I'm working with ec2 instances and was trying to execute a ruby script on another instance after ssh to that instance. 
I have a ruby script which updates configuration files, so i need to run that script as super user. when i run the script manually on that instance, `sudo ruby recreate-532d01c.rb`, the error that comes is

```
sudo: ruby: command not found
```

Running simple scripts with no root permissions works, eg.`ruby file_1.rb`.

Using rvmsudo in place of sudo executes the script with warning,

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-111:~$ rvmsudo ruby recreate-82bb000012.rb 
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.
```

I tried to execute the below command from rails console of one of the instance to test and it fails to recognize ruby as command

```
1.9.3-p545 :002 > system("ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/own_key.pem ubuntu@**.***.***.** ruby execute-52d.rb")
bash: ruby: command not found
```

I tried with possible solutions over web, but could not resolve the issue. I have the same configuration running for one of my old aws acount, this is a newly created account. Not sure if this could be issue in any way as currently ec2 instances fall under vpc by default and have some changes after dec 2013

Comment: Sounds like a simple PATH issue. Just run `type ruby` and then with sudo use the full path to the `ruby` executable.

Comment: i will check with this. thanx

Comment: @terdon i have installed rvm as a single user in the instance in which i have scripts to run after ssh. Do i need to install multi user rvm or it will work

Comment: I don't know, I don't use `ruby` but the error you get is not ruby-specific. It is simply because the ruby executable in not in root's path. Does it work if you use the whole path as I suggested?

Comment: Thanx it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting indicates that `ruby` is not in the sudo `$PATH`. TO get around this, you either need to export your environment correctly:

```
sudo -E ruby
```

Or, just use the full path. Run `type ruby` as your regular user, and use that with `sudo`. For example:

```
$ type ruby
ruby is /usr/bin/ruby
$ sudo /usr/bin/ruby
```