# bin/bash: ruby command not found. Ruby not in sudo path

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby, paths

I can't seem to run any code on ruby with any text editor. This error is returned when code is run

```
/bin/bash: ruby: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/home/user/Resume/ruby/WebScraper/redditscrape.rb"]
[dir: /home/user/Resume/ruby/WebScraper]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/.rvm/bin]
```

I found a similar question on stackoverflow [sudo: ruby: command not found after ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447681/sudo-ruby-command-not-found-after-ssh)

As user terdon explains it's caused by ruby not being in the sudo path. So I tried sudo-ing my `type ruby` but nothing happened. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

if this helps my `type ruby` is  `/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby`

and my echo path is

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Do you need the 2.2.2 version?  The ruby package on my 14.04 system is at 1.9.1, and puts ruby in /usr/bin.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `whoami; echo $PATH`

Comment: @ubfan1your $PATH shows `/bin/ruby` is not in there. try adding it by issuing this command: 


`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and fumbled to find an answer.
here is how I solved it.

- start the program with the following shibang line so that ubuntu knows it is a ruby file. `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`
- change the directory to where your code lives `cd /home/User1/program`
- make your file executable by running `chmod +x your_program.rb`
- type in the terminal `ruby your_program.rb` notice the text "ruby"

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling ruby maybe?

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ruby`

Comment: Any why? Any explanations please? :)

Comment: What's broken is something usually configured during installation. Perhaps a reinstallation will fix it. It's next in line to 'Have you tired turning it off and on again?'

Comment: I tried it and now I get a redirection forbidden error whenever I run my code.

Comment: You clearly have something wrong with the system. That is a simple remove and install command which had 0 impact on my system when I ran it just now. I suggest looking at your /bin/ folder, then /usr/bin/ to see if the Ruby app is actually present in the first place. There seems to be some useful info on how this is structured here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27213/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-windows-program-files-folder-where-do-things-g

Comment: Trying to help gets you down voted, awesome!